# Heroku - Change Log Level Runtime with Several Dynos

Tags: java, heroku, playframework-2.2

how you doing?

I have a Java Play Framework running on Heroku Server. I can change the log level in runtime of app and it works well with one Dyno. 
If I understand well, If a have more than one Dyno. Each dyno run 'one copy' on my App, but this is invisible for me. So, when I change the log level in runtime, the change will only affect 'one copy'. Is that right?

How can I change the log level to each dyno in runtime. is it posible?

Thanks!

Comment: How are you changing the log level right now? Probably not possible without restarting the dynos, or having other means of communicating with all of them to make a change.

Comment: Every Controller create its own Logger, basically with this:
Logger logger = 
        (ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeClass.clas);

To change le Log Level use this:
logger.setLevel(Level. INFO);

Works like a charm!. This is the doc http://logback.qos.ch/manual/architecture.html .

But with 2 or more dynos the scenario is complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The answer here is that all dynos will operate exactly the same. So for instance, if you enable debugging via environment variables, something like:

```
$ heroku config:set DEBUG=true
```

Then *every single dyno* you have will instantly get that environment variable set. This means that *all* your dynos will have debugging enabled.

Comment: Yes, but config:set restart the server. The switch must be runtime. On the other hand I can create Logger with diferents package name Like  com.package or com.package.SomeClass.

Comment: There's no way to change it during runtime. Also: you should NOT rely on the dyno always being up. Heroku restarts your dynos very frequently throughout the day. One of the main points of Heroku is that you should only deploy apps there which can be restarted at any point in time. That's one of the main benefits of the platform. If you require no-restarts, you *need* to use another host.